# bash - Find all files of .ts in a folder and process them

Tags: bash

I have done this in VBS, but I can't seem to wrap my head around bash, and I want to do this on a Mac.

Basically, I want to find all .ts files in a specific folder, and then run a command on them, and then move them to a new folder...so, something like:

```
For all `.ts` files in `/path /to/Recorded TV`

    -handbrakecli -i $filename -more code, etc...

    move $filename to /new/folder

loop
```

Comment: Do you know the `find` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by the bash script below:

```
for filename in /path/to/Recorded_TV/*.ts
do
    #handbrakecli -i $filename -more code, etc
    #move $filename to /new/folder
done
```

Comment: First, thanks so much!!!

I forgot one aspect of this...I would like to compare the .ts files to a list...in the Windows version, I compared to a text file, but I don't much care how.  

Basically, I have a list of show names, and I compare that to the beginning of the file name.  IE: the file name might be Castle - S01E01 -somename.ts.  I compare that to the list of names, and it would match against Castle.  If there is a match, then it would run the Handbrake command on the file.  

Is this possible?  I don't mind researching on my own, if someone could point me in the right direction!!!

Comment: I should also add that in the source file example, Castle will always be the beginning of the filename...so in the VBS script, I just used left (filename, len(string to match against))

Comment: I think I have this figured out...as soon as I test, I will post the code back.